# Insert Json Object into SQL Server 2008 using Ajax Webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax

```
function AddJSon() {
    var jsonArr = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var ProductId = $("#hfProductId" + i + "_" + j).val();
            if (ProductId != undefined) {
                jsonArr.push({
                    SalesOrderItemId: $("#hfProductId" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                    AttachmentCode: $("#txtAttachmentCode" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                    AttachmentName: $("#txtAttachName" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                    Qty: $("#txtAttachmentQty" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                    UnitCost: $("#txtAttachCost" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                    TotalCost: $("#txtAttachmentTotalCost" + i + "_" + j).val(),
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Above code i have pushed the values of various fields in Json array and now i want to save them in database without using loop.

Comment: does anyone have ans for this question please help

Comment: You haven't done anything than AddJSon() ?@grnake

Comment: I am not getting what should be my next step. I want to Insert this Json Object in Database @RangaDewasinghe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will step down the thing you want to do next.

1. Since you have already got your JSON you can create a web method in
   required page's asxp.cs.(I named it AddJSon())
2. This method should accept a parameter type of the JSON format what we already have.So create a class for that.(I named it JsonDataList)
   Your request objects should be as follows.

   ```
   public class JsonDataList
   {
       public List<JsonData> jsonData { get; set; }
   }

   public class JsonData
   {
       public int SalesOrderItemId { get; set; }
       public string AttachmentCode { get; set; }
       public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
       public int Qty { get; set; }
       public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
       public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

   }
   ```
3. Then you have to create your table for this.I assume you are using MSSQL and you would be able to create your table structure accordingly.(connection strings etc. too)
4. When part 3 is done, Your web method should be changed like following to insert data to created table.(i will do it in the web method itself which is not good)

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public static string AddJSon(JsonDataList jsonDataList)
   {
       try
       {
           using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("your_connection_String"))
           {
               con.Open();
               foreach(JsonData data in jsonDataList)
               {
                   string query  = "INSERT into table (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (@value1,@value2,@value3,..)";
                   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                   command.Parameters.Add("@value1",data.SalesOrderItemId);
                   command.Parameters.Add("@value2",data.AttachmentCode );
                   command.Parameters.Add("@value3",data.AttachmentName );
                   .
                   .
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }     
           }
           return "Success";
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           return "Error";
       }
   }
   ```

hope this might be helpful for you.This doesn't have any validations or any good practices.Just get the idea from this.